# OpenEdge ABL Add Index to table

Tags: openedge, progress-db

We need to add an index to a table in OpenEdge Progress ABL.  Is this possible?

I've seen where it's possible to add the index to a temp table, but never to an existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tom said, you can use Data Administration Tool. But, if you don't have access to it for whatever the reasons, you can use OE SQL. You can use "CREATE INDEX" statement to do this. For example:

```
CREATE INDEX test_idx ON PUB.CUSTOMER (COUNTRY,NAME) AREA "Customer/Order Area";
```

You need to have DBA privileges to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  You use the "data administration tool" to add tables, fields and indexes to a database.

This generally requires you to have a development license.

If you are an end-user of a vendor application you may not have such a license.

It is **NOT** possible to add an index to a db table via simple ABL code.  (Although you could invoke the dictionary routines that load .df files -- but that isn't the same thing and will not get you where you want to go.)

You are running Linux, thus this is a character environment.  To start the data dictionary:

```
mpro dbName -p dict.p
```

That will start a session and bring you directly to the character dictionary (aka "data administration").  It may not be pretty but it will allow you to add indexes.

Comment: We don't have the data adminsitration tool on our test server.  We were hoping to be able to do it with 4gl/ABL, or even SQL.

Comment: If you are able to create, compile and execute 4gl code then you should have access to the dictionary.  What version of progress is this?  And what OS are you running?

Comment: We are running 11.3 on CentOS 6.  We set up a test server to write code on.  We can't run the typical suite of tools on our test server.

Comment: You aren't making sense.  If you can write code on your test server, which presumably means that you can also compile it or what would be the point, then you have a development environment available.  And that includes "data administration".

Comment: I didn't build the server, I've just been tasked with developing against it, our admin said he can't install the data administration tools on the test server.  Something about not having the licenses.

Comment: That makes no sense.  You either have the development tools or you don't.  Data administration is not an option.  Try the mpro command above.  Also, run "showcfg" to find out what licenses were actually installed.